# How to explode a string and calculate a sum?

Tags: php, arrays

I want $total to be output as just a sum of a number but everytime i  sum up $total it outputs multiple numbers

```
$total =0   // i tried to use a number to sum them up
$computers = array(
"computer;DT-12;568,36;10",
 "Samsung; RS; 562,26;11",
 "Hewlett Packard;  F12; 450,23; 23",
"Toshiba; LO-34; 454,23;8",
 "Sony; Vaio 123; 232,23;5"
);
foreach($computers   as $value)
{
$product= explode(";",$value);

    $price = $product[2];

         $count = $product[3];
           $multiply = $count * $price;
$total += $multiply

}
```

expected output:

```
$total =  27004 as one number
```

Comment: 27004 is the total when I run your example, though the code is missing a couple of `;` in the file. Run `php -l your-file.php` on the command line to check the complaints.  After the foreach loop add `echo $total;` to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in your codes. Other than that, your calculation looks fine, and great job with `explode();`.

#### Code:

```
$computers = array(
    "computer;DT-12;568,36;10",
    "Samsung; RS; 562,26;11",
    "Hewlett Packard;  F12; 450,23; 23",
    "Toshiba; LO-34; 454,23;8",
    "Sony; Vaio 123; 232,23;5",
);

$total = 0;
foreach ($computers as $value) {
    $product = explode(";", $value);
    $total += (int) trim($product[2]) * (int) trim($product[3]);
}

var_dump($total);
```

#### Output:

You might check out to see if the math is right.

```
int(27004)
```

Answer (score 0):

The prices in each line use commas instead of dots to mark decimal places.  These will need to be modified before performing the arithmetic.

To isolate the required computer details, split on semi-colons with optional trailing spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WRSL6))

```
$computers = [
    "computer;DT-12;568,36;10",
     "Samsung; RS; 562,26;11",
     "Hewlett Packard;  F12; 450,23; 23",
    "Toshiba; LO-34; 454,23;8",
     "Sony; Vaio 123; 232,23;5"
];

$total = 0;
foreach ($computers as $computer) {
    $details = preg_split("/;\h*/", str_replace(',', '.', $computer));
    $total += $details[2] * $details[3];
}

echo $total;
// 27018.74
```